# Galaxy Note 3 (5.0) crashes when moving apps to SD ~30% of the time; latest crash lost some system settings & home button is now being weird

Tags: crashes, app2sd, home-button

Got a bit of a hopefully-not-*too*-interesting one :)

For reasons unknown, my (secondhand) Note 3 seems to have a bit of a tendency to crash when I use the "Move to SD card" button in *App info*. Doesn't happen every time.

By "crash", I mean that: everything freezes for about 5 seconds (I often notice this and go "...ah, it's gone again"), the screen goes black momentarily, the Samsung bootup animation runs for about a minute, and then it's back at the lockscreen. It **doesn't** show the Android logo/splashscreen that I see if I perform a device restart, just the Samsung animation.

I'm actually new to Android, so I don't know if I'm witnessing some sort of respring sort of thing or what. In any case the above is what happens.

I knew that something was a bit wonky/flaky, but I just accepted it as "normal" for this device (put it down to "eh, it's an old version of Android") and I figured the reboot-thing it was doing was resolving whatever the issue was.

The app transfer process seems to make the CPU get mildly impressively hot, but I don't expect that this has any impact. (Translation, I hope very very much that this thing was system-integrated properly and I didn't make it legitimately overheat ;))

IIUC, on Android 5, moving apps to the SD card can only be done via App info, manually, on a per-app basis. All AppMgr III can do for me to batch-move apps over is queue up hundreds of App Info windows so I can hit the *Move* button myself. Each transfer takes about 2 minutes and that's annoying enough, but the semi-continuous reboots meant I had to keep opening AppMgr, reselecting everything, ...

Soooo, I finally finished a script this afternoon (...:D...) that uses ADB to poke around in the package list, figure out what's on internal storage, open the *App info* window using the ActivityManager, figure out whether a given app is movable (based on whether the Move button is clickable), and if it is, click the Move button to move the app over. (The script also implements a bunch of heuristics to figure out when the phone has "crashed": **it's actually accessible via `adb shell` the entire time**, but a bunch of services stop then restart.)

To clarify, this script basically just poked the screen at the right moment so I didn't have to keep staring at the phone. After some final tweaks it happily dug its way down my list of (way too many) games and apps all afternoon. My **guess** is that the CPU was sitting at a *minimum* of 60° for a while. :/

I happened to check in on the phone after probably the 4th or 5th move-induced crash, and noticed it was behaving very strangely: the font settings were wrong, some persistent notifications I have open (system monitors) were gone, *and the Home button wasn't doing anything*.

My launcher configuration was still intact (whew), my phone still knew its lock code and my Wi-Fi's PSK. But things like font settings, keyboard preferences, etc etc were all gone.

Hard-resetting (Power+Home for 30sec), standard restarts, and wiping the cache partition from the recovery options have not restored my Home button's functionality.

What's really weird is that

- Pressing Home when the screen is off wakes the device up
- Pressing Home repeatedly enables Talkback
- Pressing Home twice doesn't do anything
- Pressing it once doesn't do anything
- Long-pressing doesn't open the recent activity view

Also - the quick-access buttons in the pull-down menu have all reverted back to factory settings, *and the Settings and Show-All buttons have stopped working*.

My next expected step is backing everything up and doing a full reset.

Just thought I'd share where I'm up to in case anyone has any other ideas.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you considered a flash problem,internal or on sd-card? As it happens when you move apps more likely the sd-card than the internal memory is affected. Battery is also often a potential problem, however the "soft reboot with adb connection" you described makes this very unlikely. BTW: This sort of reboot is nothing new, some apps like Magisk/XPosed manager offer it as a feature for a quick reboot.

Comment: It may well be an issue with the internal flash... :/ I hope not. In any case I'm glad to be able to say that after playing around with the default launcher for a bit my Home button is now working again: D

Comment: OK, the last issue I didn't mention but which was bugging me to no end was that my launcher choice wasn't being kept - on reboot it'd be back at "Android System". The launcher I was trying to pick was still on internal storage (and in fact couldn't be moved), but another launcher I wasn't using had gotten moved over to the SD. Once deleting said unused launcher, things seem to be back to normal :D - so it seems that the crash issue isn't causing external carnage after all.